# Is it okay to exit code or should I terminate main?

Tags: java, exception, exit

I'm new to exception handling, and I don't know where to stop my code if something unexpected occurs.

I have a program dealing with command line arguments. I store the arguments with the values in a HashMap. And I have a method called getAlgortihm which should get the algorithm from the map. E.g.: arguments: -alg shift, the method returns shift. The value shift is necessary, because another method uses it to decide what to do next.

```
public String getAlgorithm() {
        return argumentMap.get("-alg");
}
```

Is it okay to exit the code if -alg is not given (arguments: -algWrong shift)?

```
public String getAlgorithm() {
        if (argumentMap.get("-alg") == null){
            System.out.println("-alg is not given");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return argumentMap.get("-alg");
}
```

Or should I throw an exception and handle it where I call the method?

```
public String getAlgorithm() {
        if (argumentMap.get("-alg") == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("-alg is not given");
        return argumentMap.get("-alg");
}
```

Comment: I think that the second solution is much cleaner. Also, with the first solution doesn't terminate the program immediately and some code may be execute anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's poor programming practice to perform an exit from a function. It also makes testing such a function impossible.

In cases like this, where you have an error in a function, you should throw an exception and then the calling code can handle it as needed.  This also makes for testable code since your test can call and expect to get an exception which is the correct behavior in an error.

Comment: Let me also recommend a book on proper programming techniques.  My favorite is "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin.  In this particular case you are including a side-effect, and an unexpected one, in your code.  The function is called "getAlgorithm" and so I would expect it to return an algorithm and nothing else.  If it exits that is unexpected and therefore poor practice.

Comment: Is it a good idea to handle the null value in the calling code? So I check the return value of getAlgorithm() and if its null then throw an exception.

Comment: Again, it's bad practice to return null as an error flag.  The best practice is to throw an exception.  I'll also point out that the use of: "if (argumentMap.get("-alg") == null)" is poor practice.  Where does argumentMap come from?  It should be passed into the getAlgorithm function by the caller.  You are relying on an external DEPENDENCY.  If you pass it in, that's call DEPENDENCY INVERSION and is a much better practice.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to throw custom exception with proper error message instead of System.exit(1)